# Prevent access to file(s) to secure path based downloads

Tags: asp.net, security, download

It is fairly common to allow users to download a file via having some path modifier in the URL

```
 //MVC Action to download the correct file From our Content directory
public ActionResult GetFile(string name) {
    string path = this.Server.MapPath("~/Content/" + name);
    byte[] file = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(path);
    return this.File(file, "html/text");            
}
```

quoted from http://hugoware.net/blog/dude-for-real-encrypt-your-web-config

An application I'm working with has liberal path downloads ( directory based ) sprinkled throughout the application, hence it is super vulnerable to requests like "http://localhost:1100/Home/GetFile?name=../web.config" or ( ..%2fweb.config )

Is there an easy way to restrict access to the config file - do I need to provide a custom Server.MapPath with whitelisted directories - or is there a better way.
How do you secure your file downloads - are path based downloads inherently insecure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple option, assuming that **all** files in the ~/Content directory are safe to download would be to verify that the path is actually **under** (or **in**) the ~/Content directory and not **up** from it, as ~/Content/../web.config would be. I might do something like this:

```
// MVC Action to download the correct file From our Content directory
public ActionResult GetFile(string name) {
    // Safe path
    var safePath = this.Server.MapPath("~/Content");

    // Requested path
    string path = this.Server.MapPath("~/Content/" + name);

    // Make sure requested path is safe
    if (!path.StartsWith(safePath))
        // NOT SAFE! Do something here, like show an error message

    // Read file and return it
    byte[] file = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(path);
    return this.File(file, "html/text");
```

}

Comment: yes, I think adding a whitelist of accessible directories and files is the best option